# How to convert base64 image to UploadedFile Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Vue Version : `2.6.10`

Laravel Version : `6.0`

I am using this [vue upload package](https://github.com/kartoteket/vue-image-upload-resize) and everything is ok on client side (at least I think so). But on the server side, where I am using the laravel, have some problem.

Here is my vue send method:

```
        setImage: function (file) {
            let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file', file);
            axios.post(upload_route, formData , {
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
            })
                .then(response => {
                    // upload successful
                })
                .catch(error => console.log(error));
        },
```

And this is my server side method:

```
    public function upload(Request $request){
        $path = $request->file('file')->store('avatars');
        return response('upload success' , 200);
    }
```

When I upload the file to the server, it gives me this error:

> "message": "Call to a member function store() on null",

The file object I am sending in the `setImage` function is something like this (if I log it with console.log):

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/2wBDAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQE...
```

Comment: I imagine you are using vuex, do you have vuex linked with your axios calls?

Comment: @jalil No i don't use vuex i just want to upload them directly.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I believe `file` parameter on `setImage` is not a `File` object. So the `$request->file('file')` is `null`, because you attach a `string` (base64), not a file.

You told us that output from `console.log` is base64 path, then you need to convert that (base64) to file.

Since you're using Laravel, here is the technique:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;

.....

$base64File = $request->input('file');

// decode the base64 file
$fileData = base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $base64File));

// save it to temporary dir first.
$tmpFilePath = sys_get_temp_dir() . '/' . Str::uuid()->toString();
file_put_contents($tmpFilePath, $fileData);

// this just to help us get file info.
$tmpFile = new File($tmpFilePath);

$file = new UploadedFile(
    $tmpFile->getPathname(),
    $tmpFile->getFilename(),
    $tmpFile->getMimeType(),
    0,
    true // Mark it as test, since the file isn't from real HTTP POST.
);

$file->store('avatars');
```

**Update**

Since you're using [vue-image-upload-resize](https://github.com/kartoteket/vue-image-upload-resize), I check the documentation that it has built in function to change the output from base64 to blob, so you can just:

```
<image-uploader
    ...
    output-format="blob"
    ... />
```

Comment: thanks  , i do that and its says : `Impossible to create the root directory \"C:\\Users\\Mehdi\\Desktop\\rahyab\\storage\\app\\C:/Users/Mehdi/AppData/Local/Temp\".`

Comment: @meti Oh ok sorry, i've forgot something about that. I've updated the answer. Try it again.

Comment: @meti I've updated my answer to makes your life easier. You just don't read the docs. So you can use your original code.

Comment: thanks bro , i always had problem with ajax uploading. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if (preg_match('/^data:image\/(\w+);base64,/', $data, $type)) {
    $data = substr($data, strpos($data, ',') + 1);
    $type = strtolower($type[1]); // jpg, png, gif
​
    if (!in_array($type, [ 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png' ])) {
        throw new \Exception('Image Type is Not valid');
    }
    $data = base64_decode($data);
    if ($data === false) {
        throw new \Exception('Failed to Decode BASE64');
    }
} else {
    throw new \Exception('Data Not Matched With Image Data');
}
file_put_contents("image_name.{$type}", $data);//save decoded data as image 
?>
```

This decode and preg_match always worked for me whenever i have image like

```
data:image/jpeg;base64
```

Pass this data as $data and your extension type as $type

Answer (score 0):

Found better solution, when temp files deletes after script terminate

```
class FileHelper
{
    public static function fromBase64(string $base64File): UploadedFile
    {
        // Get file data base64 string
        $fileData = base64_decode(Arr::last(explode(',', $base64File)));

        // Create temp file and get its absolute path
        $tempFile = tmpfile();
        $tempFilePath = stream_get_meta_data($tempFile)['uri'];

        // Save file data in file
        file_put_contents($tempFilePath, $fileData);

        $tempFileObject = new File($tempFilePath);
        $file = new UploadedFile(
            $tempFileObject->getPathname(),
            $tempFileObject->getFilename(),
            $tempFileObject->getMimeType(),
            0,
            true // Mark it as test, since the file isn't from real HTTP POST.
        );

        // Close this file after response is sent.
        // Closing the file will cause to remove it from temp director!
        app()->terminating(function () use ($tempFile) {
            fclose($tempFile);
        });

        // return UploadedFile object
        return $file;
    }
}
```

From https://gist.github.com/waska14/8b3bcebfad1f86f7fcd3b82927576e38